# pyclipper: Crash on trivial case ("terminate called throwing an exception")

Tags: python, clipperlib

I'm trying to use the [Clipper](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php) Python [bindings](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyclipper/) to clip a line using a polygon. But the process crashes inside the bindings or the clipper library:

```
import pyclipper

pc = pyclipper.Pyclipper()

# Add a single line as the subject.
pc.AddPath([(-1, -1), (2, 1)], pyclipper.PT_SUBJECT, False)

# Add a square as the clipping region.
pc.AddPath([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1)], pyclipper.PT_CLIP, True)

# Clip the line using the rectangle.
solution = pc.Execute(pyclipper.CT_INTERSECTION, pyclipper.PFT_NONZERO, pyclipper.PFT_NONZERO)

print(solution)
```

When I run the above code, the process terminates during the call to `pc.Execute()` with the following message written to standard error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

I'm using Python 3.4.3 on OS X 10.8.5 with the newest version of pyclipper (0.9.3b0) available on PyPI, which uses Clipper 6.2.1.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in either Clipper or pyclipper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your example with Python 3.4.3 on Ubuntu 15.04 and I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ClipperLib::clipperException'
  what():  Error: PolyTree struct is need for open path clipping.
```

As the error message says, `PolyTree` struct should be used when clipping paths that are open.

Clipper library has 2 functions named `Execute` in the Clipper class. One accepts `Paths` as the solution parameter type, the other one accepts `PolyTree` as the solution parameter type. As the error message says, in your case you should use the second one. The second function is called in the `Pyclipper::Execute2` function. So replace the line 12 with the following one so that correct types are used:

```
solution = pc.Execute2(pyclipper.CT_INTERSECTION, pyclipper.PFT_NONZERO, pyclipper.PFT_NONZERO)
```

Please report if this solves your problem.

Comment: It seems that this was indeed the cause. I've replaced the call to `Execute` with your code and replaced the call to `print()` with `print([i.Contour for i in solution.Childs])`. Now I get the correct solution of `[[[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]]]`. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Mind that the result you get from `Execute2` is a tree, so printing this way will only work when the depth of the tree is 1. You can use `pyclipper.PolyTreeToPaths` function to convert it into a list of paths. Then you can print the way you did before.

Comment: Oh thanks for the pointer. `print(pyclipper.PolyTreeToPaths(solution))` it is.